# Str::ucfirst($string)) не работает. Laravel

Tags: laravel

```
dd(Str::ucfirst("test"));
```

Выдает ошибку:

> ErrorException in Macroable.php line 61: Method ucfirst does not
>   exist.

Хотя с другими методами (`lower(), stydly()...`) работает нормально.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
```

заимпортил в начале файла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Была более старая версия Laravel.
https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Support/Str.html#method_ucfirst
Появилась в версии 5.2.
Обновился :)

Answer (score 0):

Значит нет у класса Str такого метода. Почему не воспользуетесь стандартной функцией PHP [ucfirst](http://www.php.su/functions/?ucfirst) ?

Comment: А смысл использовать фреймворк тогда?

Comment: Фреймворк используется чтобы не писать с нуля кучу функций и библиотек, а использовать встроенные или подключать уже написанные, такие как валидация, роутинг, авторизация, ОРМ, связи таблиц и  другие, а не только ради хелперов. Со стандартной функцией PHP скрипт будет работать всегда быстрее.